# loop through JSON returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

Json:

```
[{"Name":"David Smith","ClaimNum":"123456789","Site":"SomeSite","ServiceDate":"2013-02-27","Program":"3","ServiceType":"168","ReportType":"ReportTypeHere","program":"Some Program 1","type":"ServiceTypeHere"},{"Name":"David Smith","ClaimNum":"123456789","Site":"SomeSite","ServiceDate":"2013-02-27","Program":"3","ServiceType":"168","ReportType":"ReportTypeHere","program":"Some Program 1","type":"ServiceTypeHere"}]
```

Javascript:

```
var obj = eval ("(" + jsonString+ ")");
var string;
for(i=0; i < obj.length; i++){
    string += obj[i].Name + " - " + obj[i].ClaimNum + " - " + obj[i].Site + " - " + obj[i].ServiceDate + " - " + obj[i].program + " - " + obj[i].type + "<br/>";
}
```

I am using eval instead JSON.parse because some of the older web browser we use do not support JSON.parse :(

Now this does work however, when I do:

```
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = string;
```

the first entry has:

```
undefinedDavid Smith
```

I read that this is caused because length cannot be used on a json object and thus you must convert to an array. I thought eval does this?

I am at a loss and would like to use straight javascript for this. However if there is no other way I can use JQUERY.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: With ```var str = '';``` and then ```str += 'David Smith';``` you should avoid the undefinedDavid Smith.

Comment: *I am using eval instead JSON.parse* — If you need a shiv, get json2.js, don't use eval.

Comment: where do I get json2.js? I imagine this is a json parser script?

Comment: @Quentin - I found json2.js, I use it like so: var json_data = JSON.stringify(obj); to turn the json data into an array?

Comment: No. You are parsing a JSON text, not converting an object into one. `var inflated_from_json = JSON.parse(string_of_json_text);`

Answer (score 3):

The initial value of `string` is `undefined`, when stringified it becomes `"undefined"`.

So `string += obj[i].Name etc etc` means `string = "undefined" + obj[i].Name etc etc`

Assign an empty String to `string` when you initialise it.

```
var string = "";
```

---

> I read that this is caused because length cannot be used on a json object and thus you must convert to an array.

"json object" is a very unhelpful term.

The `JSON` object is an object provided by browsers that has parsing and serialising methods.

A JSON text is a piece of JSON that is often misidentified as an "object".

An object in JSON is a data structure with named keys and values.

If you parse a JSON text to JavaScript (which is what you are doing with `eval`) then you'll get a JavaScript data structure. If you access the `length` property of an object, then it will be `undefined` unless you give it a `length` property. The outside data structure is an *array* and that is what you are looping over. Arrays *do* have `length` properties (equal to the value of the highest integer key name on the array).